# Keep custom Google Map overlay tiles visible after zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Tile Overlay feature of Google Map for Android to display custom map tiles, provided by third party service.

My problem is that, when user zooms the map, and it switches to next zoom level, already visible tiles are disappearing, and then `getTile()` method of my `TileProvider` implemetation is triggered. This causes unpleasant blinking of my map view, and moments when user can see only default map.

Standard Google Map behavior scales and "overzooms" currently visible tiles, until new ones are loaded. Is there any way I can create the same effect with Tile Overlay? I am aware that "overzoomed" tiles can be blurry, but that is ok in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Remove custom tiles when zoom level changed is default Android GoogleMap behavior. To "suppress" it (showing previous map when tiles for zoom±1 level still downloading ) you can:

1) create [`GroundOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) with screenshot of current map view. Screenshot of google map you can do like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773658/6950238) question of [DiscDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103584/discdev) and remove it when tiles downloaded;

2) create custom view which extends `MapView` class like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591194/6950238) answer and show in overridden `dispatchDraw()` method whatever you want;

3) you can set `ImageView` over your `MapView` and show it with screenshot on it while zoom changed and new tiles loaded. And if necessary you can translate tap events from `ImageView` to `MapView` and so on.

I prefer p.2 - create `MapView`-based custom view, override `dispatchDraw()` and show temporary map within it while new map loading.