# add Tile layer To android with thousand Points google map android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, google-maps-android-api-2, points

I have a lot of points of latitude and longitude and I will show them on the map with use of tile layers 
like heatmat who to farmer displays it's ground information my problem is that who number this points more than of 5 thousand points android can not draw to correct this tile layers in map and app is crashed and out of memory exeption is there a way that I can these points displays on the map my app is an agricultural app who provides some information to farmers and display them Where the product growth is more or less by of points latitude and longitude and a combination of colors thanks you for your answers.

Comment: Create custom `MapView`-based view and draw all (visible of course) points manually. Example of drawing on `MapView` canvas you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591194/6950238). In that case you can use custom fast algorithms for determine visible points (like [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) etc.)

Comment: I get list points of backend I can all points draw With this solution you said and just I have latiude and longitude by json if I can Use of For in draw If lake to app if this solution you said work You Save life ma thanks of you beacuse solution